# добавляется новый элемент в html, но вместо текста выходит ошибка

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Я создаю приложение для заметок и необходима функция добавления заметки.
Для ввода текста есть тег `textarea`.Отсюда я беру введенный текст и вставляю в новый созданный тег `p`

```js
function add_note() {
  var section = document.getElementById("all_notes");
  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

  var save_note = document.createElement("div");
  save_note.className = "note";

  section.appendChild(save_note);

  var text_of_note = document.createElement("p");
  text_of_note.className = "text_of_note";

  var text_for_text = document.createTextNode(textarea);

  save_note.appendChild(text_of_note);
  text_of_note.appendChild(text_for_text);
}
```

```html
<section class="create_note">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Ввод текста</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <p>Добавить дату</p>
    <input type="date">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="add-btn" onclick="add_note();">Добавить Заметку</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="notes_lists" id="all_notes">
  <!--Вот туда и добавляется новая заметка-->
</section>
```

Элементы добавляются, но на экран выводится не введенный текст, а [object HTMLTextAreaElement]. Наверное я не правильно что-то делаю с `querySelector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю насколько это приветствуется. Но мне проще и короче так делать.

```js
function add_note() {
  let section = document.getElementById("all_notes");
  let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  let html = `<div class="note"><p class="text_of_note">${textarea.value}</p></div>`;     
  section.innerHTML = section.innerHTML+html;
}
```

```html
<section class="create_note">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Ввод текста</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <p>Добавить дату</p>
    <input type="date">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="add-btn" onclick="add_note();">Добавить Заметку</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="notes_lists" id="all_notes">  
</section>
```

Comment: попробуй ввести в textarea html, например `<div>444</div>`

Comment: согласен, учту на будущее